# Pokemon game in python: classes/objects, battle and deepcopy

Tags: python, class, object, if-statement, while-loop

I'm new on python and I'm trying to do a Pokemon game (like the gameboy and nds games). I've created the pokemon and trainer classes and I want to implement the battle mechanics. I thought it was working fine, but then I found that if I lose the battle the program enters in an infinite loop.

I tried a lot to found the error and I discovered that when it exits the 'while alive(pokemon1) and alive(pokemon2)' loop, the pokemon1 hp returns to full hp but the pokemon2 remains with the current hp (I've put a print to show it). It makes non sense for me because the code is identical for both trainers. Anyone knows why is it happening? I want it to continue with the current hp of both pokemon at the end of the loops and battle.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import copy
import random

class Pokemon(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
    def ataque(self, oponent):
        oponent.hp = oponent.hp - 150 #just for a test

class Trainer(object):
    def __init__(self, name, *pokemon):
        self.name = name
        self.pokemon, self.pokemonname = [], []
        for pkmn in pokemon:
            self.pokemon.append(copy.deepcopy(pkmn))
            self.pokemonname.append(pkmn.name)

weavile = Pokemon ('Weavile', 150) #change the hp to more than 150 if you want to win
garchomp = Pokemon ('Garchomp', 250)
roserade = Pokemon ('Roserade', 160)
ambipom = Pokemon ('Ambipom', 160) 

me = Trainer('You', weavile) #or choose ambipom to win
cynthia = Trainer('Cynthia', garchomp)

def alive(pokemon): #check if the pokemon is alive
    if pokemon.hp>0:
        return True
    if pokemon.hp<=0:
        pokemon.hp=0
        return False

def battle(trainer1, trainer2): #battle between two trainers
    fight1, fight2 = True, True
    while fight1 and fight2:
        print ('Choose a pokemon:', trainer1.pokemonname)
        pokemon1 = eval(input())
        while not alive(pokemon1):
            print (pokemon1.name, 'is out of batlle. Choose another pokemon')
            pokemon1 = eval(input())
        pokemon2 = random.choice(trainer2.pokemon)
        while not alive(pokemon2):
            pokemon2 = random.choice(trainer2.pokemon)
        print (trainer1.name, 'chose', pokemon1.name, '\n', trainer2.name, 'chose', pokemon2.name)
        while alive(pokemon1) and alive(pokemon2):
            pokemon1.ataque(pokemon2)
            if alive(pokemon2):
                pokemon2.ataque(pokemon1)
            print (pokemon1.name, pokemon1.hp)
            print (pokemon2.name, pokemon2.hp)
        print (trainer1.pokemon[0].name, trainer1.pokemon[0].hp) #here its returning the original hp
        print (trainer2.pokemon[0].name, trainer2.pokemon[0].hp) #here its returning the current hp, as it should
        if not any(alive(pokemon) for pokemon in trainer1.pokemon):
            fight1 = False
        if not any(alive(pokemon) for pokemon in trainer2.pokemon):
            fight2 = False

battle(me, cynthia)
```

If you run the code in the way I wrote here, you need to choose one of your pokemon on the list (there's only one: weavile - to simplify), so just type weavile. After that, weavile will attack and then be attacked by garchomp. Weavile will be defeated (0 hp) in the first hit but after the loop 'while alive(pokemon1)...' it will show that weavile still has 150 hp and it will continue to ask you to choose a pokemon even if it's already dead.

If you want to win: choose ambipom instead of weavile in 'me' object or change the weavile hp to more than 150 in weavile object. If you do this it will run as I want and end the battle.

Comment: I could run the code and it worked somehow. Please include a specific error output you're dealing with and what is your expected output. And also, showing how to reproduce the error would be helpful, especially because your program requires user inputs.

Comment: What input should we use to lose in the game? Also, you can use `assert [a variable] == [expected value]` to raise an error and end the program even if the error only causes an infinite loop.

Comment: For me this code as i wrote is not working. Because my pokemon faints and it continues in the loop. For a while, I'm expecting any specific return of the function battle, I just want it to exit the function. But in this code, when I loose it never quits the loop and continues asking for me to choose a pokemon even if they're already dead. If I change the weavile hp to more than 150, I win the battle and it works fine, exiting the loop and returning 0.

Comment: To lose in the game you just need to run it in the way I wrote. Your pokemon (weavile) will be defeated in the first attack.  If you want to win: change the weavile hp to more than 150 or change your pokemon to ambipom

Comment: No. A lot of things are unclear. For example, we don't know how can we choose a pokemon at the beginning. You should tell us pokemon are chosen by the exact name displayed in the console, not by a list index. Without instructions, it's hard to answer.

Comment: The steps unrelated to the error should be removed or automated before you ask a question to let people focus on the problem-solving.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain better: If you run the code in the way I wrote here, you need to choose one of your pokemon on the list (there's only one: weavile - to simplify), so just type weavile. After that, weavile will attack and then be attacked by garchomp. Weavile will be defeated (0 hp) in the first hit but after the loop 'while alive(pokemon1)...' it will show that weavile still has 150 hp and it will continue to ask you to choose a pokemon even if it's already dead. Hope it's more clear now